# How can a legitimate design question be differentiated from broad, subjective, or lazy ones?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, question-quality

**Question Clarification**

Having read all related Q&A about spam magnets and other historic SO problems, there is still a need for examining how a legitimate and **incredibly useful** design question can be differentiated from

- excessively broad questions,
- lazy questions,
- or questions that invite opinion.

It is easy to dismiss this challenge as already solved and carved into granite for eternity.  For more open thinking, it may be worthwhile to list some questions lurk below the main one.  These others are other questions appearing sprinkled throughout meta community comments within related (but not duplicate) questions.

- When is a question related to design as specific as it can be for a design question but perhaps seen as too broad by many SO users?
- When is a design question perceivable as a request for opinions sufficiently define in numerical terms to be as objectively verifiable as working code?
- When is a design question constructive to the community without providing some quantifiable or provable criteria for answer?
- When does a question appear like a request for free design services but demonstrates just as much prior investigation as acceptable coding or debugging questions?

**Relation to SO Vision and Purpose**

This line of questioning has a purpose that I believe is in line with the vision and purpose of SO and constructive to software engineering progress.  It is based on the principle that design rigor is essential to system sustainability.

Rather than dismiss higher thinking with, "We don't allow," rhetoric, it may be useful to consider the necessity of design and architecture in full life cycle processes that the developer community may overlooking to its detriment.  Even authors and other leaders in the Agile community acknowledge the importance of design.

The development community relies on SO for comprehension of many things, and there has been a growing anti-pattern stemming from hacker-heroism in books and films and a misunderstanding of Agile philosophy that is hurting the industry.

It is beneficial to the expansion of automation to dissuade this anti-pattern.  Hunch-driven implementation is a paradigm that leads to constant re-implementation of the same systems in an attempt to fix the errors of previous developers followed by even less reliable system implemented by those that were sure they were improving the code base.

**Software Quality**

Total quality schemes proven economically beneficial to hosting corporations (such as Japanese manufacturing or Google) require quality at all points in a process life-cycle, especially design, and it would be wise for SO to encourage excellence in architecture and design processes.

**Some Ideas Considered**

Here are some ideas that could provide some equal treatment of questions that are more on the conceptual side while not breaking practical SO policy and tradition.

- Did the asker display evidence of a reasonable prior attempt to resolve?
- Was some quantifiable criteria set in the question?
- Did the asker specify the form of the design response, such as a sequence of higher level processes or a diagram in scalable vector graphics?
- Were the use cases and computing resource constraints adequately specified?

**Critique and Other Policy Options are Welcomed**

Comment: "software engineering progress" I wonder why there's a site called [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: SE.SE is supposed to be a site for: [software development methods and practices; requirements, architecture, and design; quality assurance and testing; configuration management, build, release, and deployment.](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7183/104338) Why aren't you satisfied with having a site for practical problems and another for more conceptual ones?

Comment: Some of the discussion around ["Gorilla vs. shark"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) might inform this, such as [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163726/how-can-i-safely-ask-for-a-language-comparison) or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116821/deciding-which-technology-to-use-questions). Not exactly the same, but the same principles.

Comment: My "reality of mainstream development" is that people with similar interest band together. People that want conceptual questions go to Software Engineering while those that prefer practical go to SO. Why should you mesh two groups that historically can't play nice with one and the other (considering that one drowns in noise, since the former group is smaller),

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can a good design question be distinguished from a bad one - yes. Will it make such question on-topic on SO - most likely no.

Good design question requires decent discussion and a lot of back and forth conversations to pick one of many good answers that suit particular instance of the problem. SO is not set up to handle such discussions.

Generally such questions require long answers that cover multiple options to be complete thus making them too broad.

It does not in any way mean that such questions are not useful for development community - there are other places that setup to discuss such questions or just provide all answers. E.g. [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7183/104338) seems to welcome at least some if not all such questions.

Comment: @DouglasDaseeco: You might try proposing another custom close reason that alludes to SE SE specifically, but note that SO already has more custom close reasons than standard, so there is strong reluctance to add another one if it's not extremely important.